# How to read a consistent version of sphinx files when reindex is running

Tags: concurrency, sphinx

I am having intermittent problems with a backup script when trying to back up sphinx index files.  The backup command is more or less just a `tar` command on all files in `/var/lib/sphinxsearch/data` with a few exclusion patterns (`spl`, `tmp`, etc...)

But the issue I'm running into is that we run almost continuous reindexes, which means the files that tar is operator on are constantly being rotated out with new versions.  I have a plan to deal with this, which is to use the sphinx lockfile:

- For every index:

  - Acquire a lock on the `.spl` file (hopefully preventing the reindex from running concurrently)
  - Add related files (`.spa`, `.spd`, `.sph`, `.spi`, `.spk`, `.spm`, `.spp`, `.sps`)
  - Release lock on the `.spl` file

---

My concern is that I can't seem to find any detailed documentation on *exactly* how the lockfiles are supposed to behave in sphinx.  This would be a tool that interacts with the concurrency of sphinx at a low level, and I see a lot of potential pitfalls (concurrency scares me).  I'm wondering if:

1. Is there somewhere I can get a comprehensive description of how lockfiles work in sphinx?
2. Is my plan for backing up sphinx even the right plan?  I looked around google and could find nothing better, but somebody knows a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the 'lockfile' - is only tested for existence. The file exists, searchd is activly serving the index. File doesnt exist, the index is safe to be recreated in place or deleted etc.

indexer will refuse to reindex an index, if the lockfile exists.

But if you specify --rotate, it will instead create a brand new version of the index (with .new. in the filename), it will not care if an lock file exists because it doesnt touch the exisiting index.

and when finished signal to searchd. searchd will then delete the active index, rename the index files, and serve the new versions (in such a way to not interupt serving - and it also keeps the lockfile in place)

---

So from that the only way to stop indexer (assuming you using --rotate), is to create indexname.new.spl - I think that might work - but never tried. I dont think it will notice if you advisory lock something.

A better, but more trickly way to get consistant backups, might be to intercept the signal from indexer to searchd. Have a process that listens to the sighup from indexer, if an backup is in progress pause until it finished, and then send the sighup to searchd.

(But it might take some work to make indexer send the sighub to your intercepter, will have to create a config file, with a fake pid file. so its the pid of the interceptor not searchd)

---

Of course the bigger question, if your indexes can be recreated so easily (you recrating them often anyway), why bother backing them up? If lost then can just be recreated.

Comment: To answer your last question: We're using a --merge strategy, which means we're constantly building deltas and then merging them into main.  When we run this constantly, it's cheap, but to build the whole thing from scratch is expensive.

That said - thanks for the description of the lockfile process.  I will give it a think and see if I can figure out something that suits my needs.

Comment: Aha -- I don't think sphinx file locking is what I need in this case.

What I need is something that prevents the delta+merge indexer and the backup from running at the same time.  Since both of these process are run by scripts I control, it should be simple enough to create my own file lock schema.  I don't know why this didn't occur to me in the first place, but it seems a cleaner solution in any case.  One of the many advantages is that it doesn't feel like I'm using some "implementation detail" of sphinx.

(.new.spl would probably also work, like you suggest -- I think this way is easier)